# How to call a method from a module of an other ruby file

Tags: ruby, methods, module

I have to Ruby files: one contains a module with some methods for statistical calculation, in the other file I want to call one of the methods in the module.
How can I do that in Ruby?

Is that the right way?

```
require 'name of the file with the module'

a=[1,2,3,4]
a.method1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Require needs the absolute path to the file unless the file is located in one of Ruby's load paths.  You can view the default load paths with `puts $:`.  It is common to do one of the following to load a file:

Add the main file's directory to the load path and then use relative paths with require:

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)
require "my_module"
```

Ruby 1.8 code that only loads a single file will often contain a one-liner like:

```
require File.expand_path("../my_module", __FILE__)
```

Ruby 1.9 added require_relative:

```
require_relative "my_module"
```

In the module you will need to define the methods as class methods, or use Module#module_function:

```
module MyModule
  def self.method1 ary
    ...
  end

  def method2
    ...
  end
  module_function :method2
end

a = [1,2,3,4]
MyModule.method1(a)
```

Comment: Very interesting `module_function :method2` method to show functions publicly

Answer (score 3):

Your way is correct if your module file is in the require search path.

If your module provide methods to be used by the object itself, you must do:

```
require 'name of the file with the module'

a=[1,2,3,4]
a.extend MyModule   # here "a" can use the methods of MyModule
a.method1
```

See [Object#extend](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-extend).

Otherwise, if you'll use the methods directly by the module, you'll use:

```
MyModule.method1(a)
```